# Dynamic PIVOT SQL Server - form/inputs example

Tags: sql-server, forms, dynamic, pivot

I need to transform the SELECT ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtOWb.png)) in a dynamic PIVOT, where there can be any forms name and each form can have different inputs name and amounts.

I already did the script to set columns according to the max number of inputs in a form. But I am not sure how to procced after that.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

DECLARE @max int = 
    (SELECT
  MAX(y.qtd)
FROM (SELECT TOP 10
  frm_Form,
  frm_Name,
  COUNT(inp_Input) AS qtd
FROM orb_Forms
INNER JOIN orb_FormInputs
  ON frm_Form = fri_Form
INNER JOIN orb_Inputs
  ON fri_Input = inp_Input
WHERE frm_Operation = 1
AND frm_Enabled = 1
AND fri_Enabled = 1
AND inp_Enabled = 1
GROUP BY frm_Form,frm_name
ORDER BY frm_Form desc) y)

WHILE (@i <= @max)
    BEGIN
        select @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME('Input' + CAST(@i as nvarchar));
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END
```

Result: [Input 1],[Input 2],[Input 3],[Input 4],[Input 5],[Input 6],[Input 7],[Input 8],[Input 9],[Input 10],[Input 11]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some test data

```
CREATE TABLE orb_Forms(
  frm_Form varchar(20),
  frm_Name varchar(20),
)

CREATE TABLE orb_FormInputs(
  fri_Form varchar(20),
  fri_Input varchar(20)
)

CREATE TABLE orb_Inputs(
  inp_Input varchar(20)
)

INSERT orb_Forms(frm_Form,frm_Name)VALUES
('1','form 1'), ('2','form 2')

INSERT orb_FormInputs(fri_Form,fri_Input)VALUES
('1','color'),  ('1','car'),
('2','test 1'), ('2','test 2'), ('2','test 3'), ('2','test 4')

INSERT orb_Inputs(inp_Input)VALUES
('color'), ('car'), ('test 1'), ('test 2'), ('test 3'), ('test 4')
```

Test query

```
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(MAX)='[Input 1],[Input 2],[Input 3],[Input 4],[Input 5],[Input 6],[Input 7],[Input 8],[Input 9],[Input 10],[Input 11]'

DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)='
SELECT frm_Form,frm_Name,'+@ColumnName+'
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES
      frm_Form,
      frm_Name,
      inp_Input,
      CONCAT(''Input '',ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY frm_Form,frm_Name ORDER BY inp_Input)) ColumnName
      --''Input ''+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY frm_Form,frm_Name ORDER BY inp_Input) AS varchar(10)) ColumnName
    FROM orb_Forms
    INNER JOIN orb_FormInputs ON frm_Form = fri_Form
    INNER JOIN orb_Inputs ON fri_Input = inp_Input
    --WHERE frm_Operation = 1
    --  AND frm_Enabled = 1
    --  AND fri_Enabled = 1
    --  AND inp_Enabled = 1
    ORDER BY frm_Form desc
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(inp_Input) FOR ColumnName IN('+@ColumnName+')) p
'

PRINT @query -- check the query

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Hey Leran, thanks for reply.

I tested and didn't work. I tought that could be because was missing inp_Input in the group by clause and missing the end "as PIVOTTABLE". After adding it, the script worked but its showing all Inputs null

Comment: I made some test data and corrected my query. It had some mistakes because I didn't test it. If it won't work please give me some real data for all tables which use into this query and I'll check my script again. And I commented `WHERE` for test. If you'll test it on real data then you need to uncomment it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Leran it's working perfectly. I will study your script now to accomplish the final result.